# AVAssetExportSession always Failed

Tags: ios, avassetexportsession

when i combine two m4a audio file and export this file then this will always give me failed.i got same question here and i try everyone's answer but not any worked for me.

```
NSString* documentsDirectory= [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* myDocumentPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"merge_audio.mp4"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myDocumentPath];//[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: myDocumentPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    //Check if the file exists then delete the old file to save the merged video file.
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:myDocumentPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:myDocumentPath error:nil];
    }

AVAssetExportSession *exporter=[[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    exporter.outputURL=url;
    exporter.outputFileType=AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch([exporter status])
        {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Failed to export audio");
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"export cancelled");
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                //Here you go you have got the merged video :)
                NSLog(@"Merging completed");

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find explainations you need within the [`error` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetExportSession/error) of your `AVAssetExportSession` just log it.